# MySQLi - Query - Fetch Row - Can't do it to update user password

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to build the user-password page where they can update their password by checking the "old_password" salt and matching it so they can change it to their new password. I just don't really know how to use MySQLi, MySQL was the easiest, but this one is just complicated and confusing at the same time for me. I'm still doing research on these and hopefully get somewhere.

Please tell me the error(s) that I've currently got below, and if you have time, could you help me fix the issue(s) below, that would be extremely helpful. I've been stuck with this for more than 4 days and couldn't do anything to fix it plus also checked the web and still no help.

```
<?php
// connect to database
$database = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname");

if(isset($_POST['update_password']))
{
    // check if old password salt matches
    $rs_pwd = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT pwd FROM users WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
    list($old) = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_pwd);
    $old_salt = substr($old,0,9);
    // check for old password in md5 format
    if($old === PwdHash($_POST['pwd_old'],$old_salt))
    {
        $newsha1 = PwdHash($_POST['pwd_new']);
        mysqli_query($database, "UPDATE users SET pwd='$newsha1' WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
        // password updated
        header("Location: /password.php?action=password_updated);
        die();
    }
        else
    {
        // password does not match, so return an error here
        header("Location: /password.php?action=password_does_not_match");
        die();
    }
}?>
```

This is my HTML Form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     <label for="pwd_old">Old Password:</label><br />
     <input type="password" name="pwd_old">
     <br /><br />
     <label for="pwd_new">New Password:</label><br />
     <input type="password" name="pwd_new">
     <br /><br />
     <input type="submit" name="update_password" value="Update Password">
</form>
```

**EDIT:** I get this error as well:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\password.php on line **xx**
```

Comment: `WHERE id=id`? you forgot a $ in there, probably, because right now you're just fetching **EVERY** record in that table. and note that had you remembered the `$`, you'd be vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and probably just have some sql syntax errors anyways.

Comment: @MarcB Hi thanks for your replay, I forgot to add the "'$_SESSION[user_id]'" next to that query "WHERE".